# In bash, "which" gives an incorrect path - Python versions

Tags: python, bash, macos

Can anyone explain how python 2.6 could be getting run by default on my machine? It looks like  `python` points to 2.7, so it seems like `which` isn't giving me correct information.

```
~> python --version
Python 2.6.5
~> which python
/opt/local/bin/python
~> /opt/local/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.2
~> ls -l /opt/local/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  24 12 Oct 16:02 /opt/local/bin/python -> /opt/local/bin/python2.7
```

When I generate an error, I see what's really getting run. Why could this be?

```
~> python -error-making-argument
Unknown option: -e
usage:     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Try `python -h' for more information.
```

And how can I correct it?

---

From suggestions in comments:

```
~> alias
alias cp='cp -i'
alias gcc='gcc -Wall'
~> type python
python is /opt/local/bin/python
```

Comment: Is python aliased to the 2.6.5 version?

Comment: type `alias` at the prompt to find out.

Comment: Try `type python` instead of `which python`. It will show you the actual thing that will run, including aliases and shell functions, whereas `which` does not.

Comment: @GreenMatt et al: I've updated my question.

Comment: Check, that you didn't do anything funny with virtualenvs

Comment: What is the output of `hash -t python`

Comment: I've left an answer down below for anyone who's interested. It contains an additional question.

Comment: You would have had more success with `type -a python`, which would have shown you all aliases/functions/PATH entries

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Bash uses an [internal hash table](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-linux-or-unix-understand-which-program-to-run-part-i.html#hashtables) to optimize `$PATH` lookups.  When you install a new program with the same name as an existing program (`python` in this case) earlier in your `$PATH`, Bash doesn't know about it and continues to use the old one.  The `which` executable does a full `$PATH` search and prints out the intended result.

To fix this, run the command `hash -d python`.  This will delete `python` from Bash's hash table and force it to do a full `$PATH` search the next time you invoke it.  Alternatively, you can also run `hash -r` to clear out the hash table entirely.

The [`type`  builtin](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins) will tell you how a given command will be interpreted.  If it says that a command is hashed, that means that Bash is going to skip the `$PATH` search for the executable.

Comment: Seems like a bug that changes to the `$PATH` variable don't clear the hash table automatically.

Comment: On my version of Bash (3.2.25 on Linux), it does.

Comment: @Mark: As Michael Hoffman said, it does clear the hash table when `$PATH` changes (tested in GNU Bash 4.1.9(2)-release on Mac OS X).  The issue happens not when `$PATH` changes, but rather when a new executable is installed into an existing directory in the path before the directory containing another executable of the same name—when `/opt/local/bin/python` gets created, Bash has no idea about that.  It could ask for file system notifications for all directories in the path, but it doesn't (maybe that would add a noticeable performance penalty?  I don't know).

Comment: see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86012/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-hash-command

Comment: I got "hash: no such directory name: python" when I ran hash -d python. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked my `.bash_profile`, and it contained the following:

```
# Setting PATH for MacPython 2.6
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Commenting this out has fixed my problem.

If someone can tell me why `which` and `type` still gave incorrect answers, I'd be very grateful, and will give them a check-mark!

Thanks for all your guidance!

Comment: Without removing that from your PATH, what are the results of `which --all python` (or the OS X equivalent)? Of `ls -l /opt/local/bin/python2.7`? Of `file /opt/local/bin/python2.7`? Of `python -v` (lowercase)? Of `hash -t python` run both before and after running `python` with the error? Of using `dtrace` on Python?