# Why or how is it that is my path is not being respected MacOSX?

Tags: macos, osx-leopard

How is it possible that the binary executed 'by default' -- ie. the first one found in my path, as returned by the `which` command, is in fact not the binary actually being executed by default?  (I'm running Mac OS X 10.5 on a 2008 MacBook Pro.)

I just installed the latest version of git by running `brew install git`

It installed the new version in a location *higher or earlier* in my path than the old binary.  However, the new version is not executed by default.  It's as if the shell had cached the location of the binary before I installed the new one - but the `which` command parses the path every time it runs.

I'd like to understand what's going on here and learn how to flush the 'cache' without having to log out or restart the machine.  This is what I'm seeing:

```
which git
```

returns

```
/usr/local/bin/git
```

while

```
git --version
```

returns

```
git version 1.6.5
```

but

```
/usr/local/bin/git --version
```

returns

```
git version 1.7.7
```

Checking further,

```
which -a git
```

returns

```
/usr/local/bin/git
/usr/local/git/bin/git
/usr/local/bin/git
/usr/local/git/bin/git
/usr/local/bin/git
/usr/local/git/bin/git
```

(yeah - there's some redundancy in my path setup.)

```
/usr/local/git/bin/git --version
```

returns

```
git version 1.6.5
```

*UPDATE* -- here's the answer bash hashes. (*from:* [In bash, "which" gives an incorrect path - Python versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746240/in-bash-which-gives-an-incorrect-path-python-versions) )

```
type git

git is hashed (/usr/local/git/bin/git)

$ hash -d git

$ type git
git is /usr/local/bin/git

$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git

git --version
git version 1.7.7
```

Comment: 'rehash' might be what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within a given instance of the shell, paths for binaries are indeed cached. The simplest way to clear this is to just open a new terminal window. But you can clear it in an existing window too by using the `hash` shell built-in (read `help hash` for details).

As for why `which` disagrees with the shell about the binary to execute, it's because `which` is a program that lives at `/usr/bin/which` and parses the `PATH` independently of the shell. If you want to see exactly what the shell is seeing, use `type` instead of `which` (and use `type -a` to see all possible results for a given command).