# Why I end with git 2.6.4 after install it on OSX 10.11.1 using brew install git?

Tags: git, macos, installation, homebrew

I already had Git installed at */usr/bin/git* probably there since I installed Xcode. Now I did `brew install git` and end with the same git version 2.6.4 installed in `/usr/local/bin/git` (of course symlinked to `/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.6.4/bin/git`). My questions is why I end with that 2.6.4 git version with Homebrew when I should get a more recent version?

```
$ git --version 
git version 2.6.4


$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git


$brew info git
git: stable 2.8.1 (bottled), HEAD
Distributed revision control system
https://git-scm.com
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.6.4 (1,402 files, 30.1M) *
  Poured from bottle
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/git.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: xz ✘
Optional: pcre ✘, gettext ✘
```

Comment: What does `type git` say?

Comment: `git is hashed (/usr/local/bin/git)`

Comment: @gsi-frank http://stackoverflow.com/a/7814468/6309 should help

Comment: Thanks a lot @VonC for your reply. Is not a problem of what binary is being executed, the problem is that the actually git version installed by Homebrew is 2.6.4. You can see that in the out of `$brew info git` where I say: `/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.6.4 (1,402 files, 30.1M) *`. Beside, I execute directly the `/usr/local/bin/git --version` and the result is the same "git version 2.6.4".

Comment: Sounds like you need to raise a bug with the homebrew folks.

Comment: Maybe try a reinstall... `brew rm git --force`, `brew install git`

Comment: @MarkSetchell That solved the problem! Why is that? Why at the first time Homebrew didn't install the latest version? I event tried before `brew uninstall git`, `brew install git` and nothing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know! I just know that if things don't do what I want them to do, I tend to smack them a bit harder with `--force` :-) Anyway, glad you are up and running.

Comment: @MarkSetchell If you put the same words in a answer instead of a comment, I will select it as the correct answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what caused the problem - could be a communications glitch, or somesuch, but... you could try a more forcible re-installation, as follows:

```
brew rm git --force
brew install git
```