# `which git` seems to be lying?

Tags: linux, macos

Can anyone explain this?  `which git` seems to be lying...

```
$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git

$ /usr/local/bin/git --version
git version 1.7.9.2

$ git --version
git version 1.7.10.4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try flushing `git` from the bash hash table used for path lookups with the command:

`hash -d git`

Then try again.

*Articles for Reference:*

- [How Linux or UNIX Understand which program to run – PART I](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-linux-or-unix-understand-which-program-to-run-part-i.html#hashtables).
- [In bash, “which” gives an incorrect path - Python versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7747378/573083).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `bash` then `type -a` is a better choice as it also displays aliases unlike `which`.